# Powershell Get List Items DataTable Group by on multiple columns/fields

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, caml-query

I am trying to use PowerShell Group-by on the DataTable obtained from the SPListItemCollection. The reason for using the PS Group-By is because the CAML query groupby options do not return the SPListItemCollection already grouped.

I can group-by on 1 column fine. However, when I group on 2 columns, I am not sure how to get my intended output.

I want to group by a field called Contractor Name and then Project Name/Number. Then I use the ConvertTo-Html to convert it to HTML which works good for 1 column. However, the intended output is:

```
 CONTRACTOR NAME
    PROJECT #
         Project Name, Total Hours
    PROJECT #
         Project Name, Total Hours

 CONTRACTOR NAME
    PROJECT #
         Project Name, Total Hours
    PROJECT #
         Project Name, Total Hours
```

I have not been able to get this output.

Here is the psuedo-code - not posting the actual code because it is very simple and nothing too fancy but let me know if someone needs to see it.

```
Retrieve SPListItems using SPList.GetItems(CamlQuery) -- this returns SPListItemCollection
GetDataTable from SPListItemCollection
Group-By the data table on Contractor (store in variable GroupedResults)
For each GroupedResult in GroupedResults --> create HTML
```

The above works good for 1 field (contractor), but when I add another field to the group-by, I cannot get it in my required output.

Can someone please help me with it?

Answer (score 0):

Sample tested script based on [this thread](http://matthewyarlett.blogspot.com/2013/09/using-powershell-to-group-and-filter.html)

```
if ((Get-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null) {
    Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
}

$siteURL="http://sp"
$site = Get-SPSite $siteURL
$web = $site.RootWeb
$splList = $web.Lists.TryGetList("Projects")
$spqQuery = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery 
            $spqQuery.Query =  
                "" 

$splListItems = $splList.GetItems($spqQuery) 
Write-Host $splListItems.Count      

$dt=$splListItems.GetDataTable()
$Contractor = "Contractor_x0020_Name";
$ProjectName = "Project_x0020_Name";
$ad = $dt | Group-Object $Contractor,$ProjectName # | Sort-Object -Property {$_.Values[1]},{$_.Count} -Descending

foreach($d in $ad){$d.Group | Format-Table @{Label="Contractor Name";Expression={$_["Contractor_x0020_Name"]}},@{Label="Project Name";Expression={$_["Project_x0020_Name"]}},@{Label="Total Hours";Expression={$_["Total_x0020_Hours"]}}}
<# or iterate
foreach($group in $ad){
    foreach($item in $group.Group){
        $item
    }
}
#>
Write-Host "---"
```